# Changing Varchar Date dd/mm/yyyy to datetime yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar

Good Afternoon,

I current need to conver one of my table columns that has dates in the varchar(10) -  dd/mm/yyyy format into yyyy-mm-dd date format

is this possible? I haven't used SQL for a while

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Which dbms are you using? The solution will probably be product specific since most products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.

Comment: Date datatype don't have an inherent format. The format which is displayed is dependent on your local settings.

Comment: Hi,I'm Using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Pedant alert: "SQL Server Management Studio" is a client application (one of many) which can connect to SQL Server. "SQL Server" is the DBMS product. Usually helps to mention the version as well, e.g. "SQL Server 2016" - probably not for this particular requirement, but it can affect other things.

Answer (score 0):

You should, if possible, change the table's structure to hold date values in a date data type column.

If you can't change the table's structure, you can use [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
SELECT CONVERT(Date, VarCharColumn, 103) As DateValue
FROM YourTable
WHERE VarCharColumn LIKE '[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
AND ISDATE(VarCharColumn) = 1
```

Comment: Its is SQL Server 2008, I get the following error when using that - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: This means that somewhere in your table there is a value that can't be converted to date with this format.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a where clause that should help incase a value does not fit the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Please note that the like part will also allow values like '39/17/0000', so there is also the use of `isdate`.

Comment: I have just tried to use this in my selection and get the following error - Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.  I need the dates to either be updated or in a new column

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question with all the details. The query I've written can't be used as a sub query since it's desinged to return multiple values.